# What is the most performant way to read an environment variable with a default?

Tags: rust

What are the differences between the following two approaches and how could they affect performance?

```
let consul_host = env::var("CONSUL_HOST")
    .as_deref()
    .unwrap_or("172.17.0.1")
    .to_owned();
```

or:

```
let consul_host = env::var("CONSUL_HOST")
    .unwrap_or_else(|| "172.17.0.1".to_owned());
```

Comment: Why don't you measure it? Here, the first option takes 92.436±0.38 ns and the second one takes 90.920±0.31 ns so the second is faster, but the difference is probably too small to matter unless you're doing it repeatedly in a very tight loop.

Answer (score 5):

In theory the latter variant is the most efficient as it only ever does one string allocation (either in `var` or in the `unwrap_or_else`), whereas the former always does one or two. However, the differences are minute at best. If you really want to go all the way on this micro-optimization (which I don't recommend), then you can avoid a needless allocation altogether with [`std::borrow::Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html):

```
fn consul_host() -> Cow<'static, str> {
    env::var("CONSUL_HOST")
    .map(Into::into)
    .unwrap_or("172.17.0.1".into())
}
```

Comment: uhm, why Cow and not `&'static str`?

Comment: @Netwave Because `env::var` returns a `Result<String, _>`, not `Result<&'static str, _>`.

Comment: Aha, true! Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you recommend it?

Comment: @Philip Because it is less readable for an optimization that almost surely is irrelevant.

Comment: @orlp Sounds wise :)